# ExitWindowsEx fails when Windows desktop Locked

Tags: windows, desktop, shutdown

Create a form (I'm using .NET 2.0) with a button click event:

```
{
Thread.Sleep(3000);
ExitWindowsEx(0,0); // shutdown
}
```

Hit the button, press <kbd>Left-WindowsKey</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to lock the desktop. The shutdown fails.

ExitWindowsEx returns 1 (Success).

Why does this API fail, and what else might fail when the desktop is locked?

Answer (score 3):

The API fails because you're on a different desktop, and are therefore no longer the interactive user.  From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376868(VS.85).aspx):

> Therefore, if you are not the
>   interactive user, the function can
>   succeed without actually shutting down
>   the computer. If you are not the
>   interactive user, use the
>   InitiateSystemShutdown or
>   InitiateSystemShutdownEx function.

Answer (score 0):

use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376873(VS.85).aspx. (InitiateSystemShutdown). ExitWindowsEx is 'interactive' logout.